# Tutorial to start with program and datatype refinement

Tags: scala, optimization, code-generation, isabelle

I read the [Code generation from Isabelle/HOL theories](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2013/doc/codegen.pdf) manual. However, I still feel a bit lost. Where do I need things like `linorder`? How can I use e.g., red-black trees to make things faster? How is a `locale` used in the context of program refinement? ...

Is there some tutorial to get started with refinement? If not, is there some short, self contained, correct Example?

---

Can we develop an example?

Let's assume we have `A :: 'a set` and we know `finite A`. How do we proceed to generate for example efficient code for `a ∈ A`?

How do we express our knowledge of `finite A`. How can we keep the mathematical theory (`a ∈ A`) separate from the code generation and optimization?

Comment: May be more suitable to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @auselen: No, StackOverflow is the right place for questions about day-to-day usage of Isabelle.

Comment: I suggest to refactor your question(s) into several (separated and) more concrete ones, since currently an answer would be somewhat open-ended. Also questions like "where do I need things like `linorder`?" and "How can I use, e.g., red-black trees to make things faster?" are rather unspecific without more context and do not fit well with the typical SO format.

Comment: For general information on data refinement in Isabelle, the PDFs available [here](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/community/Data_Refinement) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Okay, I'll try my best to answer this question. Please feel free to comment and edit to improve it. If you want the karma, you can also copy this answer and repost it (If your answer is better, I'll delete my answer).*

---

[This user-guide helped me to get started.](http://afp.sourceforge.net/browser_info/current/HOL/Collections/userguide.pdf)

---

Okay, let's assume we have our theory in the `locale MyLocale`.

```
locale MyLocale =
  fixes A :: "'a set"
  begin
    definition isInA :: "'a => bool" where
      "isInA a ⟷ a ∈ A"
  end
```

Let's assume we implement the `isInA` function by implementing the locale's `set` `A` by a `list`. 
Then, we can generate code and show its correctness

```
definition code_isInA_list :: "'a list => 'a => bool"
  where "code_isInA_list Al a ⟷ a ∈ set Al"

lemma code_isInA_list_correct: 
 "code_isInA_list Al a = MyLocale.isInA (set Al) a"
  by(simp add: MyLocale.isInA_def code_isInA_list_def)

export_code code_isInA_list in Scala file -
```

This basically yields the following Scala code

```
def code_isInA_list[A : HOL.equal](al: List[A], a: A): Boolean =
  Lista.member[A](al, a)
```

The `Lista.member` functions is a linear-time algorithm.
Can we do better?

Let's assume we have a `linorder` on our type `'a`. 
For example, we have `linorder` on natural numbers, strings, lists, tuples, ...
We express this assumption by writing `'a ::linorder` instead of `'a`.
One datatype that can leverage the `linorder` property is a red-black-tree. 
In our locale, `A` was a `set`. In sets, the order of elements does not matter. 
So we can use the more efficient red-black tree instead of lists. 
The red-black tree can be more efficient than lists because the elements can be ordered arbitrarily while lists dictate a fixed order.
To use red-black trees, we import the Collections framework from the [archive of formal proofs](http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/Collections.shtml).
At the beginning of our thy-file we add to the `imports` section

```
"./isabelle_afp/Collections/Collections"
```

Now we can implement a red-black tree (`rs`) version and show its correctness.
The function `rs_α` (type `alpha<tab>` in jEdit for the alpha) from the Collections framework maps the red-black tree to its corresponding set.

```
definition code_isInA_rs :: "('a ::linorder) rs => 'a => bool"
  where "code_isInA_rs Al a ⟷ rs_memb a Al"

lemma code_isInA_rs_correct: 
 "code_isInA_rs Ars a = MyLocale.isInA (rs_α Ars) a"
  by(simp add: MyLocale.isInA_def code_isInA_rs_def rs_correct)

export_code code_isInA_rs in Scala file -
```

We yield the following code

```
def code_isInA_rs[A : Orderings.linorder](al: RBT.rbt[A, Unit], a: A): Boolean =
  RBTSetImpl.rs_memb[A].apply(a).apply(al)
```

The `rs_memb` function has a logarithmic runtime. **TODO: really? where can I look it up?**

Let's further improve our code. Let's assume we want to stick to the `code_isInA_list` version, because lists are easier to us in our code. We can implement `code_isInA_list` in terms of `code_isInA_rs`. Therefore, we use `list_to_rs` that converts a list into a red-black tree.
With the `[code]` attribute, we tell the code generator to use the new version.

```
lemma [code]: "code_isInA_list Al a ⟷ code_isInA_rs (list_to_rs Al) a"
  by(simp add: code_isInA_list_def code_isInA_rs_def rs_correct)

export_code code_isInA_list in Scala file -
```

We yield the following code.

```
def code_isInA_list[A : Orderings.linorder](al: List[A], a: A): Boolean =
  code_isInA_rs[A](RBTSetImpl.list_to_rs[A].apply(al), a)
```

I guess creating a red-black and then do the lookup in it is more expensive than the simpler list version, but this is just an example. If we need more lookups, the red-black tree version can definitely be more efficient.

Let's test the code in Isabelle jEdit with some types. We start with natural numbers.

```
value[code] "code_isInA_list [(1::nat), 3, 7, 4] 4"
```

This results in `True`

Next, we try strings.

```
value[code] "code_isInA_list [''a'', ''b'', ''xyz''] ''b''"
```

This results in

```
Wellsortedness error:
  Type char list not of sort linorder
  No type arity list :: linorder
```

The error message tells us that no `linorder` is defined on the `string` type. So we import the following theories.

```
"~~/src/HOL/Library/List_lexord"
"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Char"
"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Char_chr"
"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Char_ord"
```

Now we get the desired result `True`. The code even works for tuples.

```
value[code] "code_isInA_list [(''a'', ''a''), (''b'', ''c''), (''xyz'', '''')] (''b'', ''c'')"
```